# Erlang compiler error

Tags: erlang

I have the following code

```
loop(Data) ->
receive
    {Key, Value} ->
    [{Key, Value}|Data];
    {Key} ->
        member(Key, Data);
14  loop(Data);
    stop ->
        io:format("server_stopped"),
        ok  
end .
```

and I get the following error (I put the line number 14 in the code)

> ./dist_erlang.erl:14: syntax error before: ';'
>   ./dist_erlang.erl:2: function loop/1 undefined
>   ./dist_erlang.erl:28: Warning: function member/2 is unused

I am not sure what the syntax problem is with the above code. I have a method called member which is giving the error because of a different syntax error on line 14 I am sure.

Any help is appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Erlang, expressions are separated by *commas* (and clauses are separated by semicolons). Try:

```
loop(Data) -> 
    receive 
        {Key, Value} -> 
            loop([{Key, Value}|Data]); 
        {Key} -> 
            member(Key, Data),
            loop(Data);
        stop -> 
            io:format("server_stopped"), 
            ok   
    end.
```

Comment: Does this mean I want to loop after receiving {Key}? I want to loop , which keeps this process running, after all clauses have been evaluated.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood what your code meant. I've revised the example and placed the `loop(Data)` outside the `receive` block.

Comment: Ok thanks, will receiving stop end the process? I only have a print statement, but I dont think that ok. stops this process or does it? thanks

Comment: Actually, on second look your code appears to have more than just that problem. I've revised my example again to show looping on the two first messages and to exit on `stop`.