# Erlang error when spawning a process

Tags: erlang

I start a process as follows

```
start() ->
register (dist_erlang, spawn(?MODULE, loop, [])),
ok.
```

But get the following error when trying to run start().

> Error in process <0.62.0> with exit value: {undef,[{dist_erlang,loop,[]}]}

The module is called dist_erlang.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Based on your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902912/erlang-compiler-error), your `loop` function takes one parameter, not none. Erlang is looking for `loop/0` but can't find it because your function is `loop/1`.

The third parameter to `spawn/3` is a *list* of parameters to pass to your function, and in the case you've shown the list is empty. Try:

```
register (dist_erlang, spawn(?MODULE, loop, [[]]))
```

In this case, the third parameter is a list that contains one element (an empty list).

Answer (score 19):

Although the question is old, I post what helped me when I was wrestling with the Erlang compiler.

This (incomplete) snippet

```
-export([start/0]).

start() ->
    Ping = spawn(?MODULE, ping, [[]]),
    ...

ping(State) ->
    receive
        ...
    end.
```

fails with error:

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 2-Sep-2013::12:17:46 ===
Error in process <0.166.0> with exit value: {undef,[{pingpong,ping,[[]],[]}]}
```

until you export explicitly `ping/1` function. So with this export:

```
-export([start/0, ping/1]).
```

it works. I think that the confusion came from some examples from [Learn You Some Erlang for great good](http://learnyousomeerlang.com) where the modules sometimes have

```
-compile(export_all).
```

which is easy to overlook

Comment: Cheers!  This solved the exact problem I had.  :)  I find it weird that you would have to export a function that you intend to use locally (through spawn).

Comment: I faced the same issue. I had to export the local function in order to be used by `spawn(?MODULE, do_chat, [Sock])` which is invoked in the same file where `do_chat` is defined.